# SQL update set and select issue,

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this code:

```
SELECT 
ZONE_NAME,
ORG_ID,
ORG_SHORT_NAME,
XMSSN_USE


FROM TABLEZ
;
UPDATE TABLEZ
SET TABLEZ.BILL_CYCLE = '1-DEC-2020 4' WHERE (SELECT TABLEZ.XMSSN_USE WHERE TABLEZ.XMSSN_USE=224)
```

But it doesn't seem to execute. What could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO. Please do not use images for posts. People that are willing to help usually will need to copy your code to test it on their own environment in order to help you. Here are more tips on how to ask a good SQL question in particular: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: Terminate your statements properly. Supply the exact statement that's failing in TEXT form.

Comment: The screen shot is missing a semi-colon relative to the code text in the question. But you should really use a semi-colon to terminate BOTH statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 different query sentences. You should use `;` after first query and then write the update query.
Also you need to use some field on the where clause, your where is empty.

Comment: UPDATE TABLEZ SET TABLEZ.BILL_CYCLE = '1-DEC-2020 4' WHERE `INSERT YOUR COLUMN HERE =` (SELECT TABLEZ.XMSSN_USE `¿¿FROM??` WHERE TABLEZ.XMSSN_USE=224). Take a look on the where sintaxy
https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-where/ and https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-subquery/